# Dotnet restore fails on Ubuntu 16.04 server in Dockerfile and outside docker

Tags: .net, docker, asp.net-core, proxy, ubuntu-16.04

When the dotnet restore command is run either inside Dockerfile or in ubuntu  shell on host, the following error is displayed:

```
 Restoring packages for /src/Customer/Customer.API/Customer.API.csproj...
 Restoring packages for /src/Customer/Customer.DTO/Customer.DTOs.csproj...
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.302/NuGet.targets(114,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json. [/src/Customer/Customer.API/Customer.API.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.302/NuGet.targets(114,5): error :   The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. [/src/Customer/Customer.API/Customer.API.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.302/NuGet.targets(114,5): error :   Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream. [/src/Customer/Customer.API/Customer.API.csproj]
```

I've also set the http_proxy and https_proxy environment variables (corporate proxy) and the docker images are downloaded with success, only this command is failing.

Edit:
The error is now this:

```
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.302/NuGet.targets(114,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json. [/home/dev/Repos/MVPChina/Customer/Customer.API/Customer.API.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.302/NuGet.targets(114,5): error :   An error occurred while sending the request. [/home/dev/Repos/MVPChina/Customer/Customer.API/Customer.API.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.302/NuGet.targets(114,5): error :   SSL connect error [/home/dev/Repos/MVPChina/Customer/Customer.API/Customer.API.csproj]
```

also, I cannot ping 8.8.8.8 or www.google.com from this ubuntu server

The curl command also fails:

```
$ curl https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json 
curl: (35) gnutls_handshake() failed: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.
```

Comment: Are you also setting the proxy within the container before restoring packages?

Comment: Yes, I used ~/.docker/config.json for setting the proxy, but also running dotnet restore outside docker and Dockerfile results in that error

Comment: Did you resolve this? I'm having a similar issue now.

Comment: Nope, I've to push docker images from local to docker hub and then deploy them on my ESX ubuntu. We have a restrictive proxy on this environments and also different DNS. The issue also appears locally on a VM when I have to connect through a VPN to have access to out intranet, the '/etc/resolv.conf' dinamically updates but I cannot do either dotnet restore locally, or access https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json with curl.